# Type initializer threw an exception

Tags: c#, initialization, static-classes

This class is throwing an exception. It doesn't show me the exact line number, but it sounds like it's occurring in the static constructor:

```
static class _selectors
{
    public static string[] order = new[] { "ID", "NAME", "TAG" };
    public static Dictionary<string, Regex> match = new Dictionary<string, Regex> {
        { "ID", new Regex(@"#((?:[\w\u00c0-\uFFFF-]|\\.)+)") },
        { "CLASS", new Regex(@"\.((?:[\w\u00c0-\uFFFF-]|\\.)+)") },
        { "NAME", new Regex(@"\[name=['""]*((?:[\w\u00c0-\uFFFF-]|\\.)+)['""]*\]") },
        { "ATTR", new Regex(@"\[\s*((?:[\w\u00c0-\uFFFF-]|\\.)+)\s*(?:(\S?=)\s*(['""]*)(.*?)\3|)\s*\]") },
        { "TAG", new Regex(@"^((?:[\w\u00c0-\uFFFF\*-]|\\.)+)") },
        { "CHILD", new Regex(@":(only|nth|last|first)-child(?:\((even|odd|[\dn+-]*)\))?") },
        { "POS", new Regex(@":(nth|eq|gt|lt|first|last|even|odd)(?:\((\d*)\))?(?=[^-]|$)") },
        { "PSEUDO", new Regex(@":((?:[\w\u00c0-\uFFFF-]|\\.)+)(?:\((['""]?)((?:\([^\)]+\)|[^\(\)]*)+)\2\))?") }
    };
    public static Dictionary<string, Action<HashSet<XmlNode>, string>> relative = new Dictionary<string, Action<HashSet<XmlNode>, string>> {
        { "+", (checkSet, part) => {
        }}
    };
    public static Dictionary<string, Regex> leftMatch = new Dictionary<string, Regex>();
    public static Regex origPOS = match["POS"];

    static _selectors()
    {
        foreach (var type in match.Keys)
        {
            _selectors.match[type] = new Regex(match[type].ToString() + @"(?![^\[]*\])(?![^\(]*\))");
            _selectors.leftMatch[type] = new Regex(@"(^(?:.|\r|\n)*?)" + Regex.Replace(match[type].ToString(), @"\\(\d+)", (m) =>
                @"\" + (m.Index + 1)));
        }
    }
}
```

Why can't I change those values in the c'tor?

Comment: One other suggestion... brush up on the [design guidelines for .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx).  It might seem picky, but camel-cased public fields, classes starting with underscores... To any .NET dev, it looks like a mess and would reflect badly on you in their eyes.

Comment: I have a hard time wrapping my head around callbacks and stuff, can you explain what the following line in your code does:  public static Dictionary<string, Action<HashSet<XmlNode>, string>> relative = new Dictionary<string, Action<HashSet<XmlNode>, string>> {
        { "+", (checkSet, part) => {
        }}
    };

Comment: @sc_ray he's got a dictionary that has a string key and a value that is an Action that takes both a HashSet of type XmlNode and a string.  He's using the dictionary type initializer shortcut, equivalent to calling `.Add("+", (checkSet, part) => { });`  which adds a new key value pair into the dictionary where the key is `+` and the value is a lambda equivalent of the following method:  `void EmpyMethod(HashSet<XmlNode> checkSet, string part) { /* nothing */ }`

Comment: @Will: I'm porting a JavaScript library (guess which one), and I'm trying to maintain most of their naming conventions so I don't confuse myself. The class starts with an underscore because I'm treating it more like a member variable than a class (it's a sub-class). The whole thing acts like a big private constant.

Comment: @sc_ray: To add on to what will said... I just haven't filled in that 'anonymous method' yet. Class is about half finished ;) Lots of constants to stuff in there yet. I might take a different approach because this is getting kind of ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're modifying a collection while enumerating it.  You can't do that.  Quick fix is to move the keys into a different collection and enumerate that:

```
static _selectors()
{
    foreach (var type in match.Keys.ToArray())
    {
```

Also, if you had checked the inner exception you would have seen that was the case.

Comment: Inner exception says "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute". I guess that should have tipped me off, but I must not have read it clearly.

Comment: @Mark: In future, if you've *got* the inner exception message, please include it in the question. I still think you should move some of this logic outside the type initializer though :)

Comment: It's almost a direct port of jQuery... blame them for weird code :p The dictionaries actually do come in handy though, because I need to access those regexes with a variable key.

Answer (score 2):

If you view the inner exception, you will see that it states

> Collection was modified; enumeration
>   operation may not execute.

This means you are changing the collection you are looping, which is not allowed.

Rather change your constructor to something like

```
static _selectors()
{
    List<string> keys = match.Keys.ToList();
    for (int iKey = 0; iKey < keys.Count; iKey++)
    {
        var type = keys[iKey];
        _selectors.match[type] = new Regex(match[type].ToString() + @"(?![^\[]*\])(?![^\(]*\))");
        _selectors.leftMatch[type] = new Regex(@"(^(?:.|\r|\n)*?)" + Regex.Replace(match[type].ToString(), @"\\(\d+)", (m) =>
            @"\" + (m.Index + 1)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, if you `ToList()` it, you can skip the `for` and just enumerate the result of that call.  Also, you're calling `ToList()` a crapton here, not exactly the best code.

Comment: Yes, that is true, and the *crap ton* to list can be moved to outside of the loop X-)

Answer (score 1):

Simple diagnostic approach: Move all that code into normal methods, and find out what exception is being thrown that way. Or just run it in the debugger - that should break when the exception is thrown.

I suspect it'll be a bad regular expression or something like that.

Personally, I think this is too much logic in a static constructor, but that's a slightly different matter... Note that you're also relying on the ordering of the initialization here:

```
public static Regex origPOS = match["POS"];
```

That *is* guaranteed to be okay at the moment, but it's very brittle.

Comment: Well, I do need a copy of `match["POS"]` before it's modified in the c'tor... where would you suggest I do that then?

Comment: @Mark: I would probably refactor most of the work into methods in a separate class. That means you can easily unit test them. You could *then* potentially use them from the static constructor.